# Redirecionamento de conexão com proxy tunneling

Tags: linux, conexão, proxy

Tenho dois servidores Ubuntu, um fica no Brasil e outro no EUA, nos dois eu ativei o IP_FORWARD para poder fazer um tunel de conexão com eles até o destino, bem, eu comprei os dois para fazer alguns testes de ping, quando eu faço a conexão com o servidor do EUA eu fico com um ping meio alto, em torno de ~250, e quando eu faco com  o servidor do Brasil eu fico um ping um pouco mais baixo ~220, porém eu fiz alguns testes...

Quando eu testo o ping do meu servidor do Brasil para o meu servidor do EUA o ping é bem menor do que o ping que pego direto da minha residencia para o EUA, e quando vejo o ping da minha residencia para o servidor do brasul o ping também é consideravelmente baixo, estava pensando então em fazer o tunel para o servidor do Brasil > EUA > Destino, porém, eu não sei como pegar essa conexão que irei receber no servidor brasileiro e redirecionar para o do EUA.

Aí que vem a duvida, não sei como fazer essa rota, alguém pode me ajudar ou dar alguma ideia ou apenas dizer se isso é possivel?

PS: Sou novato em Linux e no assunto, estou utilizando esse esquema para poder estudar mais.

PS 2: Não sei se a ideia que eu tive seria correta ou também, se eu estou fazendo esse tunel de maneira errada.

PS 3: O destino fica no EUA, o ping do meu servidor de lá até o destino é de 1.3 ms

Comment: pelo oque eu entendi vc quer conectar seus dois VPS sem envolver DNS, isso? Se sim vc pode fazer uma VPN entre os dois.